# How to Make Two Windows Applications Talk to Each Other using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Recently I went through a C# course by Bob Tabor in MSDN Channel 9 and I loved it. understood the overview of C#.

I have a stock trading application based on C# (NinjaTrader) and I want it to talk with Excel 2016. By that I mean if I draw a trend line in Ninjatrader on a candlestick chart, I want excel to understand that I drew a trendline and want it to perform a simple task like highlighting some thing or bold a specific cell based on some conditions. I want them to talk to each other in real-time. This is my requirement.

I recently hired a programmer to do this task (he is still working on the project), but I want to do this myself in the coming years as I want to "give myself wings". Having ideas but not knowing what to do to actually accomplish the task is seriously limiting me.

What I understood after going through Bob Tabor's C# course is this. In his video "Understanding Namespaces and Adding References to Assemblies", I need to use a reference to Excel's library. That part I could grasp, but when people talk about COM,Interop...

I'd call myself an Excel power user as I have good experience in developing spreadsheets with close to half-a-million vlookups on binary file format.

Can you please suggest me a course that teaches how to make two applications talk to each other? I need this course to be in C#. Also I'm not sure what next step I should take to improve my c# skills. I searched for c# in 21 days Sams book, but I couldn't find an updated version of it. All other languages had such book but not c#. I want to use my knowledge only for personal use. So, if you could suggest me a course that also helps me to reach a good c# proficiency level.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I can see you've put a huge amount of effort into your question, which is massively commendable - most of the "recommend me a" questions are a few lines and demonstrate a  serious lack of effort... however, unfortunately, it doesn't change the fact that "recommend me a" or "what is the best" themed questions are not a good fit for this site :( so you're unlikely to get any reasonable answers. I find it helps to think of SO like a dictionary- facts only. Your question has to be answered with a fact, no opinions allowed. (sorry)

Comment: I'd say ask your hired developer. He is building it for you and should be able to give you a (high level) overview of what he is doing and he might be able to point out techniques used you can learn yourself. But do mind it takes far more than 21 days to learn to create such applications :-)

Comment: Actually, I feel that my first question is specific... because I'm looking to acquire a specific skill... If you ignore my question to recommend a c# course, I think it falls within the category of acceptable questions because I could not find such a course teaching a "specific skill" very hard to find even if others feel it is "publicly available". So if any one has some experience in learning such a course, I'd be grateful...

Comment: @PeterBons Hi... You're right.. but I dont think he will share the details with me... I'll definitely try asking him after he completes the project...

Comment: For .net application in C# to do interact with excel try out https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*How to make 2 windows applications talk to each other*" is very broad definition.
there are a lot of ways to establish this.
but i feel that your wish is to understand what is an 
[Application programming interface (API).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

the developers who created excel assumed that other developers from all around the world will need the ability to "talk" with it, so they also developed a library that every programmer can implement as DLL file into **.Net** project (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace and it is a part of .net framework)
basically, this library contains **properties** and **methods** that can use in order to "talk" to excel from your .net application.

**Wikipedia:**

> An API is usually related to a software library. The API describes and
>   prescribes the expected behavior (a specification) while the library
>   is an actual implementation of this set of rules. A single API can
>   have multiple implementations (or none, being abstract) in the form of
>   different libraries that share the same programming interface. The
>   separation of the API from its implementation can allow programs
>   written in one language to use a library written in another.

every programmer that want to share his (compiled) code between projects or with other programmers can create a DLL file as an API.
 here is for example a DLL file that i have developed (and still improving) because i thought that other programmers will need this ability on their winforms projects and it will save them some time:
[Graphical Winforms Clock Charts Libary(DLL) - including Speedometer, Executive Goals Clock, Animated Wait Clock](https://github.com/Jonathan435/Business-Clocks-Charts).

so, if you need to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel just focus on the properties and methods that this dll contain: [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx)

also, there are alot of random videos on youtube with very good explanations, you can search their videos for a variety of `Interop.Excel` usages.

here is a series for beginners: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwYf_aPsuys&list=PLEdObNxHtDHI-EBwVmLLrfdsMp0hsydWV (never watched it)

**to summarize all of that, if you understand how everything is built and you will improve your programming skills you will be able to use any library very fast...**

Comment: Thanks @jonathana This is a good start. Easy to understand... First good knowledge of c#... then learn libraries of other programs that I want to work with.... okay... sounds logical..

Comment: OMG... @jonathana... Great resource... Thanks for sharing.. :)

Comment: you welcome, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

what i understand is that you need an xls/xlsx output from your project. you can implement excel functions on your project by using either office library or thrd party librarys.